# get progress database version on Unix

Tags: database

Is there a simple Unix console command to determine which version of a Progress database is running? I have root access to the Unix console.

Thanks in advance on any guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in your installation path's bin directory (usually $DLC/bin) you will find an executable called

```
pro
```

If you execute that with no parameters it should echo back some information like this, you'll notice that its letting us know the version near the end:

```
        @@@@@@   @@@@@@   @@@@@@@   @@@@@   @@@@@@   @@@@@@@   @@@@@    @@@@@
       @     @  @     @  @     @  @     @  @     @  @        @     @  @     @
      @     @  @     @  @     @  @        @     @  @        @        @
     @@@@@@   @@@@@@   @     @  @  @@@@  @@@@@@   @@@@@     @@@@@    @@@@@
    @        @   @    @     @  @     @  @   @    @              @        @
   @        @    @   @     @  @     @  @    @   @        @     @  @     @
  @        @     @  @@@@@@@   @@@@@   @     @  @@@@@@@   @@@@@    @@@@@

                           Progress Software Corporation
                                    14 Oak Park
                            Bedford, Massachusetts 01730
                                    781-280-4000

       PROGRESS is a registered trademark of Progress Software Corporation
                              Copyright 1984-2004
                        by Progress Software Corporation
                              All Rights Reserved

OpenEdge Release 10.0B05 as of Sat Apr 15 00:44:33 EDT 2006
```

P.S. I'm sorry you have to deal with progress.

Comment: Thanks for your reaction.

On running the command I get a message "This version of PROGRESS requires a startup procedure. (495)".

I know the the version has to go back at least 8 years, because that's how long the server is already running.

P.S. Me too :)

Answer (score 1):

In the BIN directory I have found some files using "ls pro*", including "proutil". This doesn't startup without a supplied databasename, but shows it's own version nevertheless.

PROGRESS Version 8.3E as of Wed .... EST 2001 in my case.

Comment: Yeah that would do it. Sorry I didn't have any older Progress installs up anymore. I had a few Solaris 8 machine with progress running on them that had Progress 8. Now everything is on RHEL 4 or 5.

Answer (score 0):

1) There is a file called "version" in the installation directory ($DLC).  The "pro" command cats this file on startup.  You can too: cat $DLC/version

2) There is also a command called "showcfg" which will provide all of your licensing data.  "$DLC/bin/showcfg".

BTW -- Progress version 8 dates from the mid 90s.  8.3E was one of the last patch releases to v8.